# Casting one-hot encoded array to bool arrays is slow

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large array with uuids, lets call it `labels`. Now I need for every different uuid in this array a bool mask which shows me at which positions in the array every uuid is located. I need this for later computations.

I use pandas' `get_dummies()` function to create a one-hot encoding of the `labels` array. Each column of the resulting dataframe is then casted to a a boolean array and stored in a dictionary. The key of the entry is the uuid.

The creation of the dataframe with the `get_dummies()` function is always as fast as I need it. But casting the columns to bools gets really slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

labels = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 500000)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 d = pd.get_dummies(labels);  d = {key: d[key].astype(bool) for i, key in enumerate(d.columns.values)}
>>52.5 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

#smaller dataset
labels = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 100000)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 d = pd.get_dummies(labels);  d = {key: d[key].astype(bool) for i, key in enumerate(d.columns.values)}
>>3.52 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

#without casting to bool
labels = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 500000)
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 d = pd.get_dummies(labels);  d = {key: d[key] for i, key in enumerate(d.columns.values)}
>>1.24 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

How can I make this faster, i.e. how can I get my boolean masks from the one-hot encoding?

Comment: Do you need the result to be a dict? Converting your dataframe to boolean values is pretty fast (just do d = d==1), converting it to dict will take most of the time.

Comment: `d=d==1` takes just as long as creating the dict (at least on my machine). Did you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert the df to boolean values you can convert it to a numpy array and compare it to 1 and make a df again:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(d.values==1)
1 loop, best of 3: 281 ms per loop
```

Its not a good idea to follow my original advice from the comment (a was short one zero when i did the timings there)

```
%timeit d==1
1 loop, best of 3: 4.83 s per loop
```

I think pandas is much slower here because its iterating over the columns internally.

edit:

to retain the original index you can do:

```
e = pd.DataFrame(d.values==1)
e.index = d.index
```

edit2:
to save another 60 ms its also possible to use pandas eval function

```
%timeit pd.eval('d==1')
1 loop, best of 3: 220 ms per loop
```

Comment: I need the original uuid somewhere as a key for later lookup. With your approach, the columns of the DataFrame get new indices. Is there a way wo tweak this?